# Where to Find container-fluid class in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

When switching from container to container-fluid, it works. However, I tried to search for it in the bootstrap.css file but could not find a match. Any idea?!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

FYI since folks answered this back in Oct 2013, boostrap 3.1 does have container-fluid: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-fluid
(container-fluid will expand your content to the full width of the page. container adds a 15px padding on the left and right).

It's defined in line 755 of boostrap.css at the time of this writing.

(What's odd is that it seems to be defined in boostrap.css the exact same way as container (with a 15px padding) but it definitely works in expanding your content to the full width of the page -- I couldn't find the difference in the CSS file.)

Comment: Hi, the difference will be seen between lines 740 and 754 which defines the maximum widths of the container at various screen sizes...

Answer (score 9):

If you read up on the [2.x to 3.x migration](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration) you'll see it's been removed for just `container`.

So, `container-fluid` would therefore be absent from the 3.0 CSS.

---

**UPDATE Aug 2014:**

As others have stated, Bootstrap versions >3.0 have brought back `.container-fluid`. However, I feel like it's worth mentioning that if you're here for exclusively 3.0, it's not available.

Comment: @workingBee: See [container](http://jsfiddle.net/s42ss/) vs the (now missing) [container-fluid](http://jsfiddle.net/s42ss/1/). (All it really does is supply a page width and add padding; the columns widths are still managed by the `col-md-*` (and other) classes.)